# Importing hash-set module not working for typescript/systemjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I'm working on an aurelia project, using typescript to create the javascript. Now I tried to add another custom library, '[hash-set](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hash-set)' (using `jspm install npm:hash-set --save`). However I can't seem to actually use this package (using systemjs as loader).

My document structure is like:

```
\
dist\
    src\
        app.html
        app.js
        main.js
jsp_packages\
    npm\
        hash-set@1.0.1\
node_modules\
index.html
config.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

The important files (I think, please state in the comments if I miss something):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="src/main">

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      SystemJS.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**
This is compiled to app.js as prebuilt step. Using es2015 as target configuration.

```
import {hashSet} from 'hash-set';

export class App {
  public myText: string;
  hashFn(value) {
    return value.toString();
  }

  constructor() {
    alert("oh");
    const h = hashSet;
    const StringSet = hashSet(this.hashFn);
    alert('oh2');
  }
}
```

**config.js**

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: false,
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  meta: {
    "bootstrap": {
      "deps": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  },
  map: { /*lots of aurelia and other library stuff*/
    "hash-set": "npm:hash-set@1.0.1"
    }
  }
});
```

And it's also listed in `package.json` @ `{"jspm":{"dependencies":"hash-set": "npm:hash-set@^1.0.1"}}}`

Now when I try to run above code (typescript compiles to app.js as prebuilt step), the `app.js/app.ts` loads, as expected. (frankly removing the hash-set specific code makes everything work as expected).

However during construction "oh" is shown, but "oh2" is never. Debugging over the code shows that "hashSet" is "undefined". Which leads me to believe that that systemjs isn't including the hash-set correctly? 
Am I missing something?

---

**EDIT:** digging into the generated js (`app.js`) file I notice something weird:

```
define(["require", "exports", "hash-set"], function (require, exports, hash_set_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    class App {
        hashFn(value) {
            return value.toString();
        }
        constructor() {
            alert('oh');
            const h = hash_set_1.hashSet;
            const StringSet = hash_set_1.hashSet(this.hashFn);
            alert('oh2');
        }
    }
    exports.App = App;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

While debugging, `hash_set_1` is actually of the type I expect `hash_set_1.hashSet` to be.  Actually manually editing the javascript to not use `hash_set_1.hashSet` but rather just `hash_set_1` works.

Trying
`import hashSet from 'hash-set';` (notice lack of {}) changes the generated javascript offending line to `const StringSet = hash_set_1.default(this.hashFn);` which is still not correct (default isn't defined either).

Comment: If `hashSet` is undefined at the line `const StringSet = hashSet(this.hashFn);` and this interrupts the execution, then the browser should give you a big fat error in the console. Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @Louis `AggregateError invoke get get (anonymous function) Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error invoking App. Check the inner error for details.` in aurelia-pal.js:38. Not too helpful, digging deeper the inner error says "`hashSet`" is not a function.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/blond/hash-set/blob/07eec478136d4daed57e1ef9998f45e30e3cc16b/index.js#L9), you'll see it is exported as:

```
module.exports = function hashSet(hashFn) {
```

Doing `import { hashSet } from 'hash-set';` cannot work because the export would have to be `module.exports.hashSet = ...`.

It should work if you do:

```
import hashSet = require("hash-set");
```

Comment: Ah, yes, the useless useless act of negation.